# java rmi notboundexception

Tags: java, rmi

> I'm trying to develop. My RMI code Initiation that had Server/Client locally for learning purposes. The server part had two interfaces Echo & Sum implemented in the serverRMI and I tried to call from the client side but got this error. Does anyone have any ideas how I can resolve this?

[image]
*Server.java*

```
public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            MyServerRMI server = new MyServerRMI();
            LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
            Naming.rebind("rmi://localhost:1099/Server", server);
            System.out.println("Server is ready for clients to connect");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Server failed: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

*MyServerRMI*

```
public class MyServerRMI extends UnicastRemoteObject implements EchoInterface, SumInterface {
    public MyServerRMI() throws RemoteException {
        super();
    }
    
    public String echo(String s) throws RemoteException {
        return s;
    }
    
    public int sum(int a, int b) throws RemoteException {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

*MyClientRMI*

```
public class MyClientRMI {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            EchoInterface objetEcho = (EchoInterface) Naming.lookup("rmi://localhost:1099/server");
            SumInterface objetSum = (SumInterface) Naming.lookup("rmi://localhost:1099/server");

            System.out.println("Echo: " + objetEcho.echo("Hello World from RMI server"));
            System.out.println("Sum: " + objetSum.sum(5, 10));
    } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Client failed: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not associated the bindings in the client. To do that, you should use:

```
Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(host);
```

or

```
Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(port);
```

and then

```
EchoInterface objetEcho = (EchoInterface) registry.lookup("rmi://localhost:1099/server");

SumInterface objetSum = (SumInterface) registry.lookup("rmi://localhost:1099/server");
```

also, please use

```
e.printStackTrace();
```

instead of just printing e, as the stack trace provides a lot more information.

Comment: It didn't work i got the same error. https://github.com/rayenCtrl/Distributed-System/tree/master/Initiation